# MongoDB aggregation pipeline to work out retention

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of users. All users have a `createdAt` and a `lastLogin` field. The `createdAt` field is a date representing when the user signed up, and the `lastLogin` field is a date representing the last time a user logged in to the site.

I'd like to work out how many users that signed up in February logged in to the site again at least 30 days after they signed up. More than this, I'd like to work out how many users that signed up in March, April, May, etc. signed back in at least 30 days after they first signed up.

I've got a similar (but **different**) method that works out how many people each month have logged in within the past 30 days already (where `fromDate` is 30 days ago):

```
const pipeline = [
    {
        $match: {
            lastLogin: {
                $gt: fromDate,
                $exists: true
            },
        },
    }, 
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                year : { $year : "$createdAt" },
                month : { $month : "$createdAt" },
            },
            sum: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
];
```

But I'm not sure how to change this to do what I want.

What I want to do is count how many people that signed up on February 1st logged in at any point after March 1st.
What the second query does is count how many people that signed up in February have signed in in the past 30 days. So if today is October 1st, it counts everyone that has signed in from September 1st and on.

Comment: What is your question? Also I suggest you include simple documents with the expected output.

Comment: is that clearer now?

Comment: What's the error ? Your query should work fine. Can you add sample doc from your collection?

Comment: There's no error with my method. It doesn't do the query I want though

Comment: I've added another comment at the end to try and explain the difference between what I'm already doing and what I want to do

Comment: your problem is difficult to solve with no example data. We need to create the data in order to test and solve it.

Comment: Do you need a query to aggregate this for *every* month in a given time-range at once, or for a single month (in you example: February)?

Comment: Exactly, for 1 month is easy and possible, tough for all months, I don't think is possible using aggregation. I create a result using map-reduce, see if that suits your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using map-reduce query, I think this is  what you need:

```
// Al 3 users were createdAt februrary 2016
db.collection.save([
    {createdAt: new Date(2016, 1, 2), lastLogin: new Date(2016, 2, 5)},
    {createdAt: new Date(2016, 1, 3), lastLogin: new Date(2016, 2, 7)},
    {createdAt: new Date(2016, 1, 2), lastLogin: new Date(2016, 1, 15)},
])


map = function() { 
    var days30after = new Date(this['createdAt']);
    days30after.setDate(this['createdAt'].getDate()+30);

    if(this['lastLogin'] >= days30after){

        // Group results based on year and month values, add 1 to month
        var key = {'year':this['createdAt'].getUTCFullYear(), 'month':this['createdAt'].getUTCMonth()+1};
        emit(key, 1);   
    }
}

reduce = function(key, values) {
    return values.length;
} 

db.collection.mapReduce(map,reduce, { out : "collection2" });

db.collection2.find().pretty()
```

Result: 2 users registered in february and singed in again after 30 days

```
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2016, "month" : 2 }, "value" : 2 }
```

Comment: Thanks! I expect the result to be: `{ "_id" : { "year" : 2016, "month" : 1 }, "value" : 2 }` since 2 people that signed up in January logged in again within a month. Once I understand this hopefully I can fix it to what I need.

Comment: In my example using the posted data, the month when user signed up is february (`new Date(2016, 1, 2)` ), in JS months are counted from 0.   IN the final result, I was 'correcting' this, by adding 1 (`getUTCMonth()+1`). Also, keep in mind that Date is time zone sensitive.